# Nginx throws connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm running Nginx server in Docker container. Full output I'm getting from nginx container:

```
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.32.1, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.32.4:3000/favicon.ico", host: "localhost"
```

this is my nginx.conf file:

```
server {



listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://client:80;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }

  location /users {
    proxy_pass        http://users:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }

  location /auth {
    proxy_pass        http://users:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }

  location /swagger {
    proxy_pass        http://swagger:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }

}
```

this is output from netstat:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8084            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1152/mono           
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1475/dnsmasq        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      820/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1007/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.11:41310      52.24.205.129:443       ESTABLISHED 5402/firefox        
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.11:52356      172.217.169.74:443      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.11:40116      79.125.108.59:443       TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.11:46750      151.101.65.69:443       ESTABLISHED 5402/firefox        
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.11:54722      35.231.145.151:443      ESTABLISHED 1193/gitlab-runner  
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.11:50634      198.252.206.25:443      ESTABLISHED 5402/firefox        
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.11:45066      54.192.137.19:443       TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.11:57006      192.0.73.2:443          ESTABLISHED 5402/firefox        
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      11972/docker-proxy  
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1007/cupsd          
tcp6       0      0 :::3007                 :::*                    LISTEN      11760/docker-proxy
```

my containers:

```
a1fc51905cae        next_tdd_nginx      "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp     nginx
36137030e482        next_tdd_client     "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:3007->80/tcp   client
4e92d8e4f723        next_tdd_users      "/usr/src/app/entryp…"   2 minutes ago        Up About a minute   5000/tcp               users
1194e66f5ed8        next_tdd_users-db   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago        Up 2 minutes        5432/tcp               next_tdd_users
```

My containers don't even use the port 3000. They use port 3000 in development but not in production and I'm working with the production build now.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: It shows http://192.168.32.4:3000/favicon.ico, there is no port 3000  in your conf file. Are you sure this is the file running?

Comment: added more details.

Comment: The evidence suggests you're using the development version of nginx configuration.